# Bar chart persist chartvalues using UserDefaults

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am trying to persist bar chart values using UserDefaults so that every time the app is invoked it doesn't show blank chart.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard        
    let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: [entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4], label: "Widgets Type")   
    let data = BarChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])  
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data)

    defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "encoded data")
    defaults.synchronize()

    if let decodedData = defaults.object(forKey: "encoded data") as? Data {
        let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedData )
        barChart.data = data as? ChartData
```

But when I run my app I get the following error message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Charts.BarChartData encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: The error means that `BarChartData` doesn't support `NSCoding` so you can't archive it.

Comment: Thank you also realized that I should have had `as? ChartData ` in line above